# Do horizontal asymptote rules for rational functions require the function to be fully simplified?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am teaching high school precalculus and have a textbook that gives the following preamble to its rules for finding horizontal and slant asymptotes of rational functions:

> Let $f(x)=\frac{a(x)}{b(x)}$ be a rational function, where $a(x)$ and $b(x)$ are polynomials with $b(x)\neq 0$ **and $a(x)$ and $b(x)$ sharing no common factors other than $\pm 1$.**

The text then lists the standard rules for finding horizontal and oblique asymptotes. (Asymptote at $y=0$ if $deg(a(x)) < deg(b(x))$, etc.)

My question: Is it necessary for the polynomials to be fully simplified (no common factors other than $\pm 1$) to apply these rules? It seems to me that this does not affect the limit behavior. Am I missing something?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

For the horizontal asymptote, you don't need to fully simplify it, just compare the power for highest order term.

For vertical and slant asymptotes, you might need to simplify and cancel common factors.